# Return an object from a parse javascript function

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am feeding a cloud function with an `objectId` and I want to perform several actions.

- First I want to find a Delivery.
- Then I want to search for something else based on the results of the query.

Here's my cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("setStartPoint", function(request, response) {
    var deliveryId = request.params.deliveryId;
    var Delivery = Parse.Object.extend("Delivery");
    var deliveryQuery = new Parse.Query(Delivery);    

    deliveryQuery.get(deliveryId, {
        success: function(delivery) {
            console.log("Delivery found: " + delivery.id );
        },
        error: function(object, error) {
            console.log("Delivery NOT found: " + error.message );
            response.error();
        }
    });
    // The problem starts here
    // I need the results of the query here:
    console.log(del.get("name"));
});
```

Is there a way to return the results from the `get()`?

Comment: Since it seems to be asyncronous you can only pass the results to the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated version using promises that should help you go in the right direction -- let me know if it needs more clarity.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("setStartPoint", function(request, response) {
  var deliveryId = request.params.deliveryId;
  var Delivery = Parse.Object.extend("Delivery");
  var deliveryQuery = new Parse.Query(Delivery);


  deliveryQuery.get(deliveryId)
    .then(function(delivery){
      console.log("Delivery found: " + delivery.id );
      response.success(delivery) //return delivery to calling function after async .get()

    }, function(err){
      console.log("Delivery NOT found: " + err.message );

      response.error(); 
    });
});
```